# controller_manager, ros_controllers and exposing a PosVel I/F in RobotHW

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I'm stumped.  So far in my ROS adventure, I have been able to instantiate a `JointPositionController`, `JointStateController`, and `JointTrajectoryController` with `controller_manager`.  Recently, I came across `posvel_command_interface.h` in (https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/tree/indigo-devel/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface) and decided to use a `PosVel` interface in my `RobotHW` class, for a couple of joints that use Robotis AX-12As.  That was easy enough to code in.

However, I then came to edit the YAML file associated with `controller_manager`, and I realized that I could not, try as I may, figure out how to replace the highlighted line to use a `PosVel` controller:

YAML snippet:

```
  # PosVel Controllers ---------------------------------------
  neck_tilt_joint_posvel_controller:
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController   # <<-- this line
    joint: neck_tilt_joint
```

After spending some time perusing the `ros_controls` source, my hypothesis is that there is no `PosVel` controller implemented that I could simply instantiate from the `controller_manager` spawner.

So therefore my question is, what do you recommend I do to communicate with my `RobotHW`'s `PosVel` command interface?  Do I need to write a custom controller that is `ros_control`-compliant, and did I miss the documentation that explains how to do that?

A related question would be, if I want to be able to modulate max velocity and position set point on AX-12As, should I approach the problem differently?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226567/controller_manager,-ros_controllers-and-exposing-a-posvel-i/f-in-robothw/) by [BigBuddha](https://answers.ros.org/users/22808/bigbuddha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My solution was to take a copy of ros_controllers/position_controllers, read up on pluginlib, and write my own simple PosVel controller that controller_manager can load. It worked.

---

Originally posted by [BigBuddha](https://answers.ros.org/users/22808/bigbuddha/) with karma: 66 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [XaviDz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27391/xavidz/) on 2016-07-04**:
Hi! I am also in your situation, I mean, I also want to control Dynamixel AX12 servos through the PosVelJointInterface. Could you please upload your posvel controller to github? I would really appreciate your help since I am running out of time to deliver my project.